# Querying for values from several models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Course` and `Lesson` models. Course has several lessons. I want to find all the lessons for currently logged in student to generate kind of timetable.

I have a method that returns all the courses that this student is studying. Now I want to get all lessons from all those courses in `@courses` into `@lessons`, something like:

```
def index
    @courses = current_student.find_courses
    @lessons = @courses.lessons
end
```

Is it possible to do it somehow simple on one line?

The find_courses method is implemented as following:

```
def find_courses
    Course.where("id IN (?)", StudentAssignment.select("course_id").where('student_id == (?)', self.id))
  end
```

The Models:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :student_assignments
  has_many :courses, :through => :student_assignments
  ....

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :room
      belongs_to :teacher
      belongs_to :course
      ....

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teacher_assignments
  has_many :teachers, :through => :teacher_assignments
  has_many :student_assignments
  has_many :students, :through => :student_assignments
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses

  def active_lessions
    Lession.joins(course: :students).where(students: {id: self.id})
  end
end
```

In this way you can directly get all active lesssions for current_user

```
current_student.active_lessions
```

Comment: This solution doesnt work me, maybe its because the relation is implemented as: `has_many :courses, through => student_assigments`. The raised error is: `undefined method lessons for #<Course::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fb88ef5f098>`

Comment: @Spasitel Can you please show me you model associations of three tables?

Comment: There was a typo - "Lession" instead of "Lesson", now I get another exception: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: courses.user_id: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "lessons" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "lessons"."course_id" WHERE "courses"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?`. I will add the associations to the question.

Comment: @Spasitel I believe course should have `user_id` as `course belongs_to user`?

Comment: Yes, but its an M:N association implemented through third table StudentAssigment. I will add the method find_courses method to the question for claryfing

Comment: @Spasitel `Lession.joins(course: :students).where(students: {id: self.id})` How about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@lessons = @courses.flat_map(&:lessons)
```

It takes each course in `@courses` list and gets the list of lessons for that course.